# ConcurrentModificationException TimerTask

Tags: java, arraylist, timer, timertask, concurrentmodification

I get `ConcurrentModificationException` when I start a second timer after canceling the first one. Both timers uses a separate `ArrayList` and iterates through it. No removal/modification is performed on the list, still there is thrown `ConcurrentModificationException`.

This happens when I stop the first timer and start the second one right away. If I wait few seconds before initiating the second timer, then it works fine.

I ended up making a copy of the incoming list on both timers, passing the copy to the timer, still I get the error. Not sure why as I am iterating through the list and merely reading the values.

Code for Timer #1:

```
private void timerwork(final List<Object> list) throws IOException {
    timer = new Timer();
    final List<Object> taskList = list;
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new CustomTimerTask(taskList) {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (taskList != null && !taskList.isEmpty()) {
                synchronized (taskList) {
                    for (Object o: taskList) {
                        try {
                            // this method takes each object, 
                            // does some logic and writes to a flat file, 
                            // it does not modify the object itself, 
                            // but just reads it and does some calculation 
                            // on some local variables
                            valueIncrementOperation(o);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                timer.cancel();
                timer.purge();
                throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage(), e);
            }
        }
        //once exited out of the loop, it copies the flat file to another file
        try {
            copyFileUsingFileChannels(source, finaldest);
        } catch (IOException ignore) {
        }
    }
}

public synchronized void valueIncrementOperation(Object o) throws IOException {
    DataInputStream d = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(sourcefile));
    DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(tempfile));

    initialValue = Long.parseLong(o.getDefaullt_value());
    String count;
    String t;
    while ((count = d.readLine()) != null) {
        String u = count.toUpperCase();
        String[] z = u.split(" ");

        if (z[0].contains(o.getO())) {
            // .............. *snip* ..............
            out.writeBytes(t + "\n");
        }
    d.close();
    out.close();
    copyFileUsingFileChannels(source, initialDest);
}
```

CustomTimerTask code:

```
public class CustomTimerTask extends TimerTask {
    private List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();

    public CustomTimerTask(List<Object> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

Timer 2 has similar logic: ie, it makes copy of the incoming list before passing to timer2.

Still I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "Timer-0" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:859)
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:831)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
```

A work around is to wait few seconds before starting timer2. Is there a better way to address this scenario?

Comment: obvious question: what is at com.comcast.ams.simulator.service.OidTypesDao$2.run(OidTypesDao.java:307) ? (obvious answer : you are in a foreach loop in which you remove items from your list.)

Comment: `this.list = list;` doesn't make a _copy_ of the list, it just makes a new reference to the _same_ list.

Comment: A simple solution would probably be to replace your List with a java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList. This will likely fix your problem.

Comment: @DavidC -  i am copying list even before calling the timer constructor    `final List<Object> taskList = list;` and pass in `taskList` to constructor

Comment: change it to `final List<Object> taskList = new ArrayList<Object>(list);` to make a copy, or use a copy-on-write implementation as @Gennaro mentioned.

Comment: @GennaroDeLuca:  thanks bro.. I thought about it too.. But i got class cast exception when converting from arrayList...need to look into it..

Comment: @DavidC - that did the trick... `final List<Object> taskList = list;`  wasn't really making a copy I believe... `List<Object> taskList = new ArrayList<Object>(list);` -- this works... Thanks bro...

Comment: use `Vector` instead, it is synchronized (handles concurrent operations)

Answer (score 2):

We know from the stacktrace that the exception is being thrown from inside an `ArrayList`. So let's take a look at the lines of code which are handling `List`s. (Superfluous code removed for ease of reading)

First there is the method call:

```
private void timerwork(final List<Object> list) {
    final List<Object> taskList = list;
```

This means that `taskList` is **the exact same object** as was passed in (called `list`).

Second, this `List` is passed into the constructor for `CustomTimerTask`.

```
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new CustomTimerTask(taskList) {
```

Third, let's examine that constructor:

```
private List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
public CustomTimerTask(List<Object> list) {
    this.list = list;
}
```

So your `new ArrayList` is thrown away, and replaced with the argument `list`, which we know is **the exact same object** as was originally passed to `timerwork()`.

I know you said:

> I ended up making a copy of the incoming list

But this is not seen in any of your posted code. Also, we do not know (because you have not posted) the calling code for `timerwork()`, but *just maybe* it goes something like this:

```
List<Object> list = ....
timerwork(list);
timerwork2(list);
```

If this is so, then we see that both timer tasks are operating on **the exact same object** in different threads, which would explain `ConcurrentModificationException`.

A simple fix, and a good practice even if my diagnosis is incorrect, would be, in the constructor of `CustomTimerTask`:

```
private List<Object> list;
public CustomTimerTask(List<Object> list) {
    // CustomTimerTask gets its own copy to play with
    this.list = new ArrayList<Object>(list);
}
```